# In R- How do I strip this data to raw values and append as a column?

Tags: r

I can't find the search terms to solve this.  This is one column from the output of an analysis and I would like to append it as a column in another data frame.  It appears to have a bunch of extra attributes and I can't get the raw strings in column format.  Any advice?

```
> df$OLNA
 [1] "XLOC_000635" "XLOC_004899" "XLOC_006006" "XLOC_006925" "XLOC_007145" "XLOC_007849" "XLOC_016798" "XLOC_017628" "XLOC_026226"
[10] "XLOC_026406" "XLOC_029462" "XLOC_032836" "XLOC_033738" "XLOC_034567" "XLOC_044525" "XLOC_044527" "XLOC_047457" "XLOC_047458"
[19] "XLOC_047981" "XLOC_051412"

> is(df$OLNA)
 [1] "character"               "vector"                  "data.frameRowLabels"     "SuperClassMethod"        "characterORconnection"  
 [6] "characterORNULL"         "atomic"                  "EnumerationValue"        "characterORMIAME"        "index"                  
[11] "atomicVector"            "characterOrRle"          "FactorOrCharacterOrNULL" "vectorORfactor"        

> as.factor(dtf$OLNA)
 [1] XLOC_000635 XLOC_004899 XLOC_006006 XLOC_006925 XLOC_007145 XLOC_007849 XLOC_016798 XLOC_017628 XLOC_026226 XLOC_026406 XLOC_029462
[12] XLOC_032836 XLOC_033738 XLOC_034567 XLOC_044525 XLOC_044527 XLOC_047457 XLOC_047458 XLOC_047981 XLOC_051412
```

Comment: `as.character`?

Comment: This isn't a reproducible example: we need the expected result and some sample data. Read `?dput` and the many answers explaining how to generate a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your dataframes have the same number of rows? Are you trying to append or join?

If it's the latter, I would start with the `join` family of functions from the `library(dplyr)`.

e.g.

```
full_df <- left_join(df, other_df, by="OLNA") #or some other identifying column that exists in both dataframes.
```

In my experience, `dplyr` will deal with the character/factor problem for you without have to use `as.character()` or `as.factor()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include an example data set and the expected output. Going off what you wrote and the comment in the question I guess it would be the following

```
 df$newCol <- as.character(df$OLNA)
```